# how to set reminder using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, recurrence

In the database, project_details table is there. I am fetching the data from database and result like json given below;

Recurrence start date is there in the database table but I am not saving the end date in the database. End date is depending upon the user selection from the fields (from date and to date)

```
{
   "projectremindshow":[
      {
         "project_ID":"8",
         "project_title":"abc",
         "period_type":"Yearly",
         "recurrence_date":"2021-10-28",
         "reminder_set_days":"12",
         "recur_every":"2",
         "start_date":"2021-09-28"
      },
      {
         "project_ID":"10",
         "project_title":"xyz",
         "period_type":"Yearly",
         "recurrence_date":"2021-10-05",
         "reminder_set_days":"13",
         "recur_every":"4",
         "start_date":"2021-09-05"
      },
      {
         "project_ID":"11",
         "project_title":"mno",
         "period_type":"Monthly",
         "recurrence_date":"2021-10-01",
         "reminder_set_days":"10",
         "recur_every":"8",
         "start_date":"2021-09-21"
      }
   ]
}


const inputList = [
  {

       date: new Date("2021-01-01"), 
       date2: new Date(todate_recu_view), 
       daysBefore: reminder_set_days, 
       period: period_type, 
       skip: recur_every
  }]

const frequencyList = inputList.map((el, index) => {
  return getPaymentPlan(el)
})
```

How to pass each for loop values to inputList?

From these project list, i want to find out the reminder dates for a month or week or year like by user select from and to date option to select the date period.

Based on the above JSON i want to show an HTML table with all reminder dates.

I have two fields from and to date and search button.Once click search button result table will be shown.

**expecting output example1 is**
if user choose from-date= 2021-01-01 and to_date=2026-01-30 and display the result like below
Html table look with two columns like below:

```
project Title reminderdate
abc           2021-09-28 /*show from start_date value from json and recur every 2 years (count upto to_date=2026-01-30) */
abc           2023-09-28 /*recur every 2 years*/
abc           2025-09-28 /*recur every 2 years*/
xyz           2021-09-05 /*recur every 4 years*/
xyz           2025-09-05 /*recur every 4 years*/
mno           2021-09-21 /*recur every 8 months*/
mno           2022-05-21 /*recur every 8 months*/
mno           2023-01-21 /*recur every 8 months*/
mno           2023-09-21 /*recur every 8 months*/
mno           2024-05-21 /*recur every 8 months*/
mno           2025-01-21 /*recur every 8 months*/ 
mno           2025-09-21 /*recur every 8 months becoz user select to_date=2026-01-30*/
```

**expecting output example2 is**

if suppose user choose from-date= 2025-01-01 and to_date=2026-01-30 and display the result like below

```
project Title reminderdate
abc           2025-09-28 /*recur every 2 years*/
xyz           2025-09-05 /*recur every 4 years*/
mno           2025-01-21 /*recur every 8 months*/ 
mno           2025-09-21 /*recur every 8 months*/
```

can anyone plz help me to do this?

code i tried:

```js
$('#find_recurrence').click(function(event) {
  var getID_comp = $('#getID_comp').val();
  var fromdate_recu_view = $('#fromdate_recu_view').val(); //2025-01-01
  var todate_recu_view = $('#todate_recu_view').val(); //2026-01-30
  
  $.ajax({
    url: base_url + "index.php/welcome/list_all_projects_reminder/",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      "company_id": getID_comp
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var new_data = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(new_data) //above mentioned JSON result


      for (var i = 0; i < new_data.projectremindshow.length; i++) {
        var sl = i + 1;

        var project_ID = new_data.projectremindshow[i].project_ID;
        var project_title = new_data.projectremindshow[i].project_title;
        var recur_every = new_data.projectremindshow[i].recur_every;
        var period_type = new_data.projectremindshow[i].period_type;
        var reminder_set_days = new_data.projectremindshow[i].reminder_set_days;


        const getPaymentPlan = ({
          date,
          date2,
          daysBefore,
          period,
          skip
        }) => {
          const originalDate = new Date(date.getTime()); // original copy before mutating
          const startDate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() - daysBefore))

          // date has been mutated. giving it previous value
          date = new Date(originalDate.getTime())

          const recurObj = {
            "recurrenceList": []
          }

          while (startDate.getTime() <= date2.getTime()) {
            recurObj.recurrenceList.push(startDate.toISOString().split('T')[0])

            switch (period) {
              case 'monthly':
                startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() + skip)
                break;
              case 'yearly':
                startDate.setFullYear(startDate.getFullYear() + skip)
                break;
              default:
                recurObj.recurrenceList.push("wrong period type is given")
                break;
            }
          }

          return recurObj
        }

        const inputList = [{

          date: new Date("2021-01-01"),
          date2: new Date(todate_recu_view),
          daysBefore: reminder_set_days,
          period: period_type,
          skip: recur_every
        }]

        const frequencyList = inputList.map((el, index) => {
          return getPaymentPlan(el)
        })
        console.log(frequencyList)

      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237840/discussion-on-question-by-remesh-sree-how-to-set-reminder-using-jquery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you hadn't got past the point of assigning the results from the AJAX into an array (because you had `inputList` outside the `for` loop, where the values were not defined or looped over), in the end there were so many other small things wrong with the code, especially inside the `getPaymentPlan` function that it's impossible to list them all here.  Instead I simply provide a working version for you to study and learn from.

Also your expected results as stated in the question are incorrect - you've asked for it to show the reminder date, but then what you've listed are the recurrence dates. All the reminder dates are several days earlier (as controlled by the `reminder_set_days` property).

The results my demo produces show the actual reminder date instead:

```js
$('#find_recurrence').click(function(event) {
  var fromdate_recu_view = $('#fromdate_recu_view').val(); //2025-01-01
  var todate_recu_view = $('#todate_recu_view').val(); //2026-01-30

  //hard-code data instead of AJAX, for this demo:
  let new_data = {
    "projectremindshow": [{
        "project_ID": "8",
        "project_title": "abc",
        "period_type": "Yearly",
        "recurrence_date": "2021-10-28",
        "reminder_set_days": "12",
        "recur_every": "2",
        "start_date": "2021-09-28"
      },
      {
        "project_ID": "10",
        "project_title": "xyz",
        "period_type": "Yearly",
        "recurrence_date": "2021-10-05",
        "reminder_set_days": "13",
        "recur_every": "4",
        "start_date": "2021-09-05"
      },
      {
        "project_ID": "11",
        "project_title": "mno",
        "period_type": "Monthly",
        "recurrence_date": "2021-10-01",
        "reminder_set_days": "10",
        "recur_every": "8",
        "start_date": "2021-09-21"
      }
    ]
  };

  let inputList = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < new_data.projectremindshow.length; i++) {
    var proj = new_data.projectremindshow[i];

    //add a new entry to inputList for each entry returned from the AJAX call
    inputList.push({
      dateFrom: new Date(fromdate_recu_view),
      dateTo: new Date(todate_recu_view),
      daysBefore: proj.reminder_set_days,
      recurrenceDate: new Date(proj.start_date),
      period: proj.period_type,
      skip: proj.recur_every,
      title: proj.project_title
    });
  }

  const frequencyList = inputList.map((el, index) => {
    return getPaymentPlan(el)
  });
  console.log(frequencyList);
});

/* the getPaymentPlan function is standalone, it should not be within a loop or within any other callback functions! */
const getPaymentPlan = ({
  dateFrom,
  dateTo,
  recurrenceDate,
  daysBefore,
  period,
  skip,
  title
}) => {
  //start from either the recurrence start date, or the start date in the form - whichever is later
  let startDate = (recurrenceDate.getTime() > dateFrom.getTime() ? recurrenceDate : dateFrom);
  //reminders go out several days before the actual recurrence start date
  startDate = startDate.subtractDays(daysBefore);

  let recurObj = {
    "project": title,
    "recurrenceList": []
  }

  while (startDate.getTime() <= dateTo.getTime()) {
    recurObj.recurrenceList.push(startDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]);

    switch (period) {
      case 'Monthly':
        startDate = startDate.addMonths(parseInt(skip));
        break;
      case 'Yearly':
        startDate.setFullYear(startDate.getFullYear() + parseInt(skip));
        break;
      default:
        recurObj.recurrenceList.push("wrong period type is given")
        break;
    }
  }

  return recurObj;
}

/* below are some functions to correctly add / subtract days and months from a Date, accounting for leap years, differing month lengths, etc */
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date;
}

Date.prototype.subtractDays = function(days) {
  var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - days);
  return date;
}

Date.prototype.addMonths = function(months) {
  var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
  var d = date.getDate();
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + months);
  if (date.getDate() != d) {
    date.setDate(0);
  }
  return date;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
From date: <input type="date" id="fromdate_recu_view" /><br/> To date: <input type="date" id="todate_recu_view"><br/>
<button id="find_recurrence">Find Recurrence</button>
```

Here is an alternative version of the getPaymentPlan function which will output the data in a format which may be easier to sort, and also to output later according to your desired HTML format:

```
const getPaymentPlan = ({
  dateFrom,
  dateTo,
  recurrenceDate,
  daysBefore,
  period,
  skip,
  title
}) => {
  //start from either the recurrence start date, or the start date in the form - whichever is later
  let startDate = (recurrenceDate.getTime() > dateFrom.getTime() ? recurrenceDate : dateFrom);
  //reminders go out several days before the actual recurrence start date
  startDate = startDate.subtractDays(daysBefore);

  let recurrenceList = [];

  while (startDate.getTime() <= dateTo.getTime()) {
    recurrenceList.push({ "project": title, "reminderDate": startDate.toISOString().split('T')[0] });

    switch (period) {
      case 'Monthly':
        startDate = startDate.addMonths(parseInt(skip));
        break;
      case 'Yearly':
        startDate.setFullYear(startDate.getFullYear() + parseInt(skip));
        break;
      default:
        recurrenceList.push({ "project": "wrong period type is given", "reminderDate": null })
        break;
    }
  }

  return recurrenceList;
}
```

Comment: can u plz give me a solution for this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69457789/how-to-filter-the-reminder-date-for-the-current-month

Comment: You still didn't update the question with _your_ attempt to solve it. And now the previous comments here seem to have been removed by somebody so there's no record of it. Edit that question please to show your genuine efforts, then I might look at it later. By now you've had more than enough time to think about the logic you need, and then try to turn that into code.

Comment: It's the same code I already gave you here, just with a couple of extra console.log() commands. You've made no attempt to make it use the start_date (instead of the reminder date) as the cut-off. Until you actually show proper evidence of having tried something I'm not doing anything else for you. You've had **a lot** of help and time already, it's time for you to step up a bit. You kept saying it's urgent and yet two days later you don't even have 1 line of code to show for your efforts to solve this reasonably small requirement? Don't tell me it's urgent if you didn't work on it.

Comment: thats y i mentioned i dont know how to resolve it. am new to javascript. i cant fix this. tried but getting all different dates.

Comment: If you're new to Javascript then why on earth are you trying to code something this complicated?? It's way beyond beginner level - as proved by the fact you haven't managed to actually write a single line of any of it yet.

Comment: But the little change you want to do now with the dates is much more self-contained and you _could_ try it. The first step though is to forget about JS specifically, and think through the logic of what you want to do...write out on paper the steps you think you need to go through (you need to think like a computer for this, one tiny step at a time), and once you're happy with that, only then do you try to work out what actual code would be needed to accomplish it.

Comment: yes, u r right. I agree

Comment: can you plz refactor my loop for this time. i wont ask u again

Comment: once this is finished. I need to start the other ..all others are pending now. so am requesting help. I won't ask you again

Comment: Hint: It should just be a 1-line change. You need to compare each reminderDate (which comes as `startDate` in the code) with the `dateFrom`, and use that to decide whether to add the reminder to the recurrenceList or not. That's what I mean by thinking through the logic before you write the code - you could implement the above in any language. Now you need to write that as JavaScript code...it should be 1 line. Give it a try and show me what you write. I think you can try this, it will be good for you - doing it is the best way to learn. If your attempt doesn't work then I can help more.

Comment: P.S. Your expected result is incorrect in your new question - your start_date is `2020-12-02`, which means the next recurrence will be `2021-06-02`. But that's the next _recurrence date_, not the _reminder date_. As per the data, the reminder is expected 30 days before that, so it would be `2021-05-02`. But as I understand it, you're asking that this reminder date is not shown in the results since it's before the dateFrom, so that's what the change I've described would achieve.

Comment: the reminder is expected 30 days before that, so it would be 2021-06-02 only. "recurrence_date":"2021-01-01", from this data am calculating 30days before so i got the start date as 2020-12-02.. from this start date only am getting all other recurrence dates

Comment: `"recurrence_date":"2021-01-01", from this data am calculating 30days before`. No you're not. Look at the code - it uses `start_date`. `recurrence_date` is never used. When I was writing ths and we were discussing it, you specifically asked for `start_date` to be used. Now I think you don't even know what you want or what your data is doing, which is probably why you're confused about what result to expect. If you can't even be clear about what you want, then it's not very surprising that you can't write code to achieve it. Clear specifications are a prerequisite to correct code.

Comment: start date as 2020-12-02 and my recurrence dates are like 2021-06-02,2021-12-02,2022-06-02,2022-12-02,2023-06-02,2023-12-02 so on................................these all the dates are reminder date for me.

Comment: That doesn't fit the pattern in the JSON you showed in _this_ question though. e.g. in the first object in this question, recurrence_date and start_date are 1 month apart. But reminder_set_days is only 10 days. So in my code I calculated the reminder date as being 10 days before the startDate. That's what your original code was attempting to do, and that's what you marked as correct in this answer. Are you now changing the requirements? If we use should start_date as the reminder date, then what is the purpose of "reminder_set_days"? Yet again, you don't seem to know what you really want.

Comment: I think you need to go back to the beginning, and write a **clear, unambiguous** set of rules which explain the meaning of each field in your JSON, and how it should be used for calculating the recurrence dates and reminder dates you expect. Then write out, on paper, the calculation which should be used to calculate each of those dates based on the input values. It should be clear enough that someone could follow the instructions and make these calculations manually without a computer. Once you've done that, _then_ you're ready to write code to automate the process.

Comment: sir your right."recurrence_date":"2021-01-01", am not using anywhere in the code. Am using "start_date":"2020-12-02" from this i want to know which date is next reminder date . so some project have monthly reminder and yearly reminder also there. Lets take now monthly. if Recur every "3" months then next date is 2021-03-02, 2021-06-02,2021-09-02 so on....................

Comment: lets take yearly, "project_title":"Help AG", is yearly reminder project. so "start_date":"2021-05-02". Recur every 1 year. so next reminder date is 2022-05-02, 2023-05-02,2024-05-02

Comment: from the above monthly project example , If user select, from date ->2021-06-01 and todate-> 2021-06-31 . then output show 2021-06-02 with project name.Thats it.

Comment: So actually then you are telling me that the fields "recurrence_date" and "reminder_set_days" are not needed? In that case why did you show them in the question? And why did you have code in your question which uses the reminder_set_days? And why did you accept an answer which uses it in the code? Can you see why I'm confused?

Comment: yes the fields "recurrence_date" and "reminder_set_days" not needed.

Comment: Ok then. So I think you really need to start this whole process again and ask a new question which does not include those fields and makes the requirements much clearer

Comment: when user adding a new project with name, details and all that time user will enter "recurrence_date": "2021-10-01" and reminder set day:30 .next then i calculate 30 days before of the recurrence date and save 2021-09-02 as startdate.

Comment: i will edit the same question sir

Comment: `next then i calculate 30 days before of the recurrence date and save 2021-09-02 as startdate`...well 1) you don't really need to do that, because you could just write code to calculate it as you go along. One rule of databases is you don't need to store data which you could calculate! And 2) according to your examples above you've done the calculation incorrectly because the start_dates you've shown are not the result of subtracting the reminder_set_days from the recurrence_date.

Comment: In my opinion it would actually be much better to get rid of "start_date" and simply provide the raw recurrence_date and reminder_set_days information in the JSON. It would then be a much simpler change to our existing code in order to calculate the reminders the way you're expecting.

Comment: yeah that also fine.i will remove start date..as per the recurrence_date will find out the recurring dates

Comment: yes edited my new question

Comment: when user select from and to date if it is june month .only that june month reminder date needs to display .no need to show for all the other months